# Is is possible to rerun failed cucumber tests in parallel?

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

Is there a way to pass a text file with failed cucumber features to parallel_cucumber?

**Example:**
You have a cucumber.yml with a parallel profile

```
#cucumber.yml
parallel: -r features --format ParallelTests::Cucumber::FailuresLogger --out rerun.txt
```

you can run

`bundle exec parallel_cucumber -o "-p parallel"`

You can run the output `rerun.txt` file with the command

`bundle exec cucumber @rerun.txt`

How can I rerun the failures in parallel?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am looking to run a similar manifest in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this after a bunch of googling/trial and error. Settled on this for the rerun command.

```
bundle exec parallel_cucumber -n 40 -o "-p parallel" --group-by scenarios `cat rerun.txt`
```

They key part is **--group-by scenarios `cat rerun.txt`**

The other stuff in there is just the syntax for specifying a cucumber profile with parallel tests and the number of threads to run it on.

The full makefile for the CI job looks like this:

```
FEATURE?=features/

run_tests:
    @echo ---- running tests ----
    @bundle exec parallel_cucumber -n 40 -o "-p parallel" ${FEATURE} --ignore-tags @flaky,@broken --group-by scenarios || \
    @if [ -s rerun.txt ]; then \
        echo "-------> tests failed, rerunning" ; \
        RERUN='RERUN ' bundle exec parallel_cucumber -n 40 -o "-p parallel" --group-by scenarios `cat rerun.txt`; \
    fi

.PHONY: run_tests
```

Thanks @dSkech for reminding me to answer my own question.

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.2.0 and seems that option `--groups-by scenarios`is no longer supported. 
`.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/parallel_tests-2.2.1/lib/parallel_tests/cucumber/scenario_line_logger.rb:10:in `initialize': ScenarioLineLogger not supported anymore after upgrading to Cucumber 2.0, please fix! (RuntimeError)`